# lightweight implementation of semiempirical quantum chemistry (e.g. MNDO,AM-1,PM3)

Tags: c++, c, quantum-mechanics

I'm searching for semi-empirical quantum chemistry solver which would be easy to integrate into my own software. I found a few implementations which can be in principle used e.g. [MOPAC](http://openmopac.net/), [ORCA](https://orcaforum.cec.mpg.de/), [SQM](http://alma.karlov.mff.cuni.cz/bio/99_Studenti/99_Later/07_VMD_Structure_Building/00_Software/Amber15_sqm.pdf) some of which are integrated e.g. into [Molecular Design Toolkit](https://autodesk.github.io/molecular-design-toolkit/features.html#molecular-mechanics). But I don't want to depend on 1GB packages when I need only a few functions. Also I wan't something where I can dig-in and modify it more easily.

I wonder if there is something more convenient with respect to following aspects:

- As much open as possible (GPL or better MIT licence)
- compact and simple to understand code-base (small number of lines, clear readability - no fortran77, minimum of external dependencies)
- C/C++ (optionally with python interface) ... I don't want to bother with frotran-C or fortran-python interface.

This is in principle continuation of my previous question
[Simple open-source Quantum chemistry or DFT code in C/C++](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/26847/simple-open-source-quantum-chemistry-or-dft-code-in-c-c). While [Libint](https://github.com/evaleev/libint/wiki/using-modern-CPlusPlus--interface-v22) is very nice software, full Hartree-Fock is too slow for me. I really would like something cheaper, like semiempirical methods and DFTB.